# How to assign "Multi-Project Throttle Category" in a script

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I am using Jenkins with Throttle Concurrent Builds plugin to ensure exclusive access to USB device in test jobs. I use parametrized jobs, with a parameter named MODE. For some MODE values the test uses USB device and for the other MODE values the test does not use the USB device. 
I am writing a Groovy script for running the tests.
Is it possible to assign "Multi-Project Throttle Category" in a script, so that I could assign it based on the value of my MODE parameter?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the categories in-place did not work for me. Instead I had to create a new `ThrottleJobProperty` and add it:

```
ThrottleJobProperty jobProperty = item.getProperty(ThrottleJobProperty)

println("ThrottleJobProperty of " + item.name + " has categories: " + jobProperty?.categories)
String category = "long-running"
if (!jobProperty?.categories?.contains(category)) {
    if (jobProperty != null) item.removeProperty(jobProperty)

    List<String> categories = jobProperty != null ?
            new ArrayList<String>(jobProperty.categories) :
            new ArrayList<String>()
    categories.add(category)
    jobProperty = new ThrottleJobProperty(
            /*maxConcurrentPerNode:*/ 0,
            /*maxConcurrentTotal:*/ 0,
            /*categories:*/ categories,
            /*throttleEnabled:*/ true,
            /*throttleOption:*/ 'category',
            /*limitOneJobWithMatchingParams:*/ false,
            /*paramsToUseForLimit:*/ '',
            /*matrixOptions:*/ null
    )
    item.addProperty(jobProperty)
    println("Assigning ThrottleJobProperty.categories for " + item.name + ": " + jobProperty?.categories)
    item.save()
}
```

Comment: I try to run this and I can't find this constructor for ThrottleJobProperty. do you now why?

Comment: Most likely it is different in your plugin version. Have a look at the available constructors and try to adapt.

Comment: thanks man! I don't have paid attention for this detail

Answer (score 0):

I found this working

```
tjp = myjob.getProperty(hudson.plugins.throttleconcurrents.ThrottleJobProperty)

// see what we got
if(tjp != null) {
    println("--- Throttle concurrents for " + myjob.name + " ---")

    try {
        println "Got this: " + tjp.categories + " items " + tjp.categories.size
    } catch(Exception e) {
        println(tjp.categories)
    }
}

// change the first one
tjp.categories[0] = "myCategory"

// update job properties
myjob.addProperty(tjp)
```

Comment: Does this modify the job configuration, or the build property? Does it take effect before the Throttle Concurrent Builds plugin blocks its execution?  Or does it modify the job externally and then trigger a build of it?  I'd like to have a parameterized job where the parameter is essentially the multi-project throttle category, where I can run multiple jobs with the same and different parameters, as well as the same job with different parameters, and each category would block appropriately (similar to your use case: different devices by USB connections)